# I lose data context when i generate template with parameters

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

when I generate subtemplate in #each helper and i add parameter, then i lose data context, what is normally visible.

I found workaround by passing data fields to template by

```
{{> productItem parameter="test" name=name details=details}}
```

, but for more complicated collections that would be very tiresome... isn't there better option to solve that problem ?

```
<template name="main">
    {{#each products}}
        {{> productItem parameter="test"}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="productItem">
    <div class="product">
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <p>{{details}}</p>
        <p>{{parameter}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

And javascript :

```
Template.main.helpers({
    products: function(){
        return Products.find({});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a new context ( it doesn't magically merge everything ), but its easy enough to include the original context.

you go :-

```
 {{> productItem product=this parameter="test"}}
```

then

```
<template name="productItem">
    <div class="product">
        <p>{{product.name}}</p>
        <p>{{product.details}}</p>
        <p>{{parameter}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

or

```
<template name="productItem">
    <div class="product">
       {{#with product}}
        <p>{{name}}</p>
        <p>{{details}}</p>
       {{/with}}
        <p>{{parameter}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```